# How to determine if two directed probabilistic graphical models are I-equivalent?

Tags: probability, graphical-model, bayesian-network, equivalence

I'm trying to figure out how to determine if these two models are I-equivalent. Google didn't properly give me a solid answer so far. Any idea on to determine it?
Thank you.
[image: Image of two models]

Comment: equivalent in which sense? their joint distributions are different.

Comment: How do you generally theorize if they the two directed probabilistic graphical models are equivalent or not?

Comment: @RinW Where did you find this problem? Is it online somewhere with solutions?

Comment: @Abraham it was online, but I can't remember the source of it since it was almost a year ago. Sorry

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Equivalence definition matters here. But, I-equivalence is a common query in Bayesian Networks, in which I just assumed you're asking for that, but you need to specify in your question as well. For two BNs to be I-equivalent, they need to have the same skeleton, and *immoralities*. Check the [lecture](http://courses.cms.caltech.edu/cs155/slides/cs155-04-learning-marked.pdf) here. Immorality is defined as a V-structure that a node $X$, having parents $Y,Z$ without an edge in between them.

In your graphs, the skeletons are clearly the same. And, the only V-structure in both graphs is the $B,C,D$ triple. So, the two graphs have the same V-structures and they are I-equivalent.

Comment: Thank you, I'm trying to find its equivalence by same set of independence assumptions. 

If the structure changes, C->B and D->B would the same equivalence exist since the skeleton changes?

Comment: Yes, this is I-equivalence: check this also: http://ai.stanford.edu/~moises/tutorial/sld019.htm

Comment: So according to the second link, the second network on it is not i-equivalence because it does not share the same V-structure, right? The link between D & E.

Comment: Yes, on the right figure S,E,D create a new V-structure, that's not present on the left one. Similarly for C,E,D.

Comment: I think the same logic applies when https://imgur.com/YzA9Toc is considered as well. Since the V-structures changes for B between the two.

Comment: first of all, the skeleton changes in that image.

Answer (score 2):

You can read [section 9 of this article](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~epxing/Class/10708-17/notes-17/10708-scribe-lecture2.pdf) and this piece of information would be helpful:

> I-equivalence can be determined by looking at the skeleton graphs,
>   i.e. the graphs formed by converting directed edges to undirected
>   edges. Two graphs are I-equivalent if they have the same skeleton and
>   the same set of v-structures

In your case, you just compare the v-structures in each graph(both contain only $B\rightarrow C \leftarrow D$) and remove the direction to compare the skeleton(the same), so they are I-equivalent.